# Can I estimate a generator matrix Q of a Continuous Time Markov Chain using discrete time without an absorbing state?

Tags: markov-chains, markov-process

I have discrete time data with 7 states and none are absorbing. Is it possible to estimate the generator matrix Q of the CTMC using the discrete time data? My concern is that the examples I've seen have a default state but mine doesn't. If so, what is the process and will the constructed CTMC be Markovian?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "discrete time data"?

Comment: I have annual observations of credit ratings for 155 companies.